# Firestore (9.1.3): Connection WebChannel transport erroned / Work on web browser but not on device mobiles (IOS/Android)

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

After upgrading from firebase v8 to v9 I have this problem, writing to firestore works fine in web browser but not on IOS / Android (no writing is done), after few minutes I have this warning:

```
@firebase/firestore:, Firestore (9.1.3): Connection, WebChannel transport errored:, me ...
```

summary of the code

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"

const app = initializeApp(config)
const db = getFirestore(app);

const MyComponent = () => { 

 ...

 useEffect(() => {
      (async function zda() {
        await setDoc(doc(db, "users", "mario"), {
          employment: "plumber",
          outfitColor: "red",
          specialAttack: "fireball"
        })
      })()
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I solved my problem with this line

```
const db = initializeFirestore(app, {useFetchStreams: false})
```